# moving to MySQL 6.0 is a good move?

Tags: mysql

what is most important issues and cautious we have to do before upgrade to MySQL 6.0?

How do you do the upgrade? setting up a new slave and do yum upgrade? what is the best way to upgrade with minimal downtime?

Comment: Do you mean 5.6? Even the latest version 5.7 is in milestone phase.

Comment: MySQL 6.0 does not exist anymore : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619894/mysql-6-0-release-date

Answer (score 1):

Moving to MySQL 6.0 is highly regarded as a bad move by most people, as it only briefly existed on the control version system of MySQL A.B. plus some very unstable alpha releases. MySQL 6 promised too many features to be able to be delivered, although some of its features were later ported to 5.5 and 5.6. Others, like SQL-layer foreign keys or the Falcon engine never saw the light. The order is more or less:
5.0, 5.1, 6.0 (not released), 5.4 (not released), 5.5, 5.6, 5.7 (not yet released)

You can watch the story by yourself, recounted in first person by a former employee [on this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T53xe_54EUY).

Regarding the upgrade (assuming you really meant 5.6), having a minimal HA setup is a must. I wrote [a more detailed guide on a previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58663/what-is-the-best-way-to-upgrade-a-mysql-version-in-a-linux-server/78428#78428), but every setup is different, and all potential problems are too many to summary in an answer, even between 2 specific versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 6.0 does not exists.
The latest version that is in production is [5.6.21](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

MySQL 5.7.4.

I am not sure what version are you using today. But if you are not using 5.6.16 and up you should upgrade.

Even Facebook are working on upgrading form MySQL 5 to MySQL 5.6 as it is the most power full version yet. MySQL 5.7 have a lot more improvements but it is still buggy so I would not put in on a production system yet.

Comment: I already mentioned that MySQL 6.0 no longer exists in my comment (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82184/moving-to-mysql-6-0-is-a-good-move#comment148208_82184)